# Subclass of UITableviewContrller exception in IOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6

This code snipped worked just fine in iOS5.1, but i'm having an issue win iOS6.

```
rightNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:parkViewController];
[rightNav.view setFrame:[detailView bounds]];
[rightNav.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];

[detailView addSubview:rightNav.view];
```

*The application is crashing with the following exception:
[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "ParkViewController" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'*

**parkViewController** is a subclass of UITableviewController.

**detailView** is a UIView.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You say `parkViewController` is a subclass of `UITableView`.

You should make this a subclass of `UITableViewController` instead

In that case, make sure that the controller's tableView outlet is correctly connected in the nib.

Comment: parkViewController is a subclass of UITableViewController.  I'll modify the question to avoid the confusion